# XSD XML Analysing the xs:sequence

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

The xs:sequence says that the elements should be in sequence. Suppose I have the xsd as shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="personinfo">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Which of the below two XMLs would be correct?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<personinfo>
  <firstname>Abc</firstname>
  <firstname>Xyz</firstname>

  <country>CountryOfAbc</country>
  <country>CountryOfXyz</country>
</personinfo>
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<personinfo>
  <firstname>Abc</firstname>
  <country>CountryOfAbc</country>

  <firstname>Xyz</firstname>
  <country>CountryOfXyz</country>
</personinfo>
```

Comment: This is a reasonable question, but what it lacks is any indication that you tried to validate your two sample XML documents against your schema (e.g. using the online validator to which I link in my answer) and the finer point(s) underlying your doubt what is valid according to your schema.  Regardless, you should have all you need across the answers offered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither.

What would conform with the schema is...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<personinfo>
  <firstname>Abc</firstname>
  <country>CountryOfAbc</<country>
</personinfo>
```

...*or*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<personinfo>
  <firstname>Xyz</firstname>
  <country>CountryOfXyz</country>
</personinfo>
```

You can validate an XML document against your XSD schema using an [online XML validator](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation) if you don't have one locally.

*If what you really want is 1 or more `personinfo` elements in succession* - for example...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<people>
  <personinfo>
    <firstname>Abc</firstname>
    <country>CountryOfAbc</country>
  </personinfo>
  <personinfo>
    <firstname>Xyz</firstname>
    <country>CountryOfXyz</country>
  </personinfo>
</people>
```

...try a schema like this instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="people">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="personinfo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Otherwise see @kjhughes' answer for schemas that describe the two sample documents you offered in your question.

Answer (score 2):

**Neither of those two XML documents instances would be valid against that XSD.**

This XML document instance would be valid for your XSD:

```
<personinfo>
    <firstname>Abc</firstname>
    <country>CountryOfAbc</<country>
</personinfo>
```

Or, you could adapt the XSD to make your given two XML document instances be valid via the use of the `maxOccurs` [occurrence constraint](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#OccurrenceConstraints).

**For your first example:**

```
<xs:element name="personinfo">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="2"/>
      <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="2"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

**For your second example:**

```
<xs:element name="personinfo">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence maxOccurs="2">
      <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I prefer it this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="personinfo">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="record" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Thus the XML will be:

```
<personinfo>
    <record>
        <firstname>Abc</firstname>
        <country>CountryOfAbc</country>
    </record>
    <record>
        <firstname>Xyz</firstname>
        <country>CountryOfXyz</country>
    </record>
</personinfo>
```

Comment: I stand corrected. Adding `maxOccurs="unbounded"` attribute to `record` element.

Comment: This is another option centered around what I think (per my answer) @cprasad may really want based on experience - and given multiple `firstname` and `country` elements in his example XML documents.  Note that I corrected the quotes around some of the attribute values in your schema; maybe a tool in the copy/paste chain to get the schema into your answer mucked with them; but it was clear what you meant and easier I thought to just clean them up than ping you with another comment to do so.

Comment: Thanks for making the quotes point. Yes, it came from a series of copy-and-paste and find-and-replace.